# How long should I do my boss's job before i get a promotion

Tags: promotion

I have this great little job doing incredibly monotonous work.. outbound soft sales calls. It's boring and takes zero creativity or ingenuity. What does.. is managing the data flow around my job. So I decided to give my boss some ways to help with problems like data duplication, lost data and overwritten data.. then I made an advanced python spread sheet to implement everything.. Now we are transitioning to using the system i designed... and I'm back making monotonous calls. How long should I keep giving my boss suggestions and solutions for her problems before I demand a promotion or quit?

Comment: Does your organization employ people in roles that do this sort of thing? Are you certain that offering this sort of work is a part of your boss' job description?

Comment: have you talked with your boss about this?

Comment: If you were to quit, what would you do? What is stopping you from doing that now?

Comment: @Upper_Case this is precisely the type of work my boss needs to be doing. If not my bosses boss as well.

Comment: @d_hippo Not yet, I may lack that kind of confidence

Comment: @Seth R Continue working to create a VR game dev company.

Comment: @Tasha, ok, so if your goal is create VR game dev company, why are you concerned about getting a promotion here? What do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: I don't know what world you all are from. But in my world if you don't have a job your required to hate yourself and be depressed as well as suicidal.. Eventually will die due to lack of food or poor nutrition.

I guess I'm hoping to save up enough money to make it happen.

Comment: Like [this one](https://av.tib.eu/media/20123)?

Comment: @Konrad Nope, but thank you for the link. I'm interested to see what he came up with. 
I'm using girst. https://www.getgrist.com/ Though I was considering building the application from scratch.. my work schedule just doesn't allow it. because not only would I be responsible for creating the application but also making calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### As long as you feel comfortable working that way, or until a better job opportunity appears. Whichever comes first.

This is a tricky spot to be in. You have a reliable job, but would like to do something more interesting. Preparing these sorts of productivity- and workflow enhancing tools is a *great* way to show that you are capable of working in that role, as well as your work ethic and ambition.

The catch is that the employer is currently getting that work, essentially without paying you for it (presuming that it's beyond what your current job description covers, not requiring overtime to develop, and so on). At some point, working that way will be exploitative, or at least will clearly not be a vehicle for enhancing your career.

Some workplaces will be excited by what you can do, and will try to move you into a role which has that sort of work as a core responsibility. If no such role currently exists, some companies will create one in order to keep you on. Other companies will be more than willing to suck the free, extra labor out of you while paying you only for a less specialized task. It will be difficult for us, as internet strangers, to know how your company operates in this regard without descriptions of events over long time periods.

But you don't have to worry about which type of employer you have. You need only worry about your own career. You can talk to your boss directly about your goals, along the lines of

> I love doing work like this, and would really like to move into a role that allows me to do it full time.

I absolutely *do not* recommend presenting this as "doing your boss' job". It's pretty common for managers to feel that their time is best used by utilizing information to make decisions, rather than compiling that information (and that feeling can be justified, or not, depending on circumstance). Even if you were to take your boss' job, that role may not allow time for tool development and validation-- that's what the [Peter Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle) is all about. Regardless, saying "I'm doing your job for you" is not going to come across as anything other than an insult, and **insulting your boss will not help you.** Even if you're correct in every detail, and *especially* if you're not correct about some things.

Instead, talking with your boss about your career goals, and more importantly, the **additional value you can bring to the company through being promoted to do this work rather than your current job** will help you here. If the work is as good as you say, and they're not getting it from anywhere else, they may be very willing to lay out a promotion schedule (or similar) for you. If they're unreceptive, you can polish your CV and add these workflow improvements you've implemented to it.

---

As for demanding a promotion or quitting, I say **don't quit until you have another (ideally better) job lined up**, and **don't demand a promotion unless you're ready to quit.**

Demanding a promotion when you aren't sure one is available only works if you have leverage, which I'm not sure you have here. If you demand a promotion and don't get it, you'll still be stuck in the job you dislike and the most you can do is stop giving your employer free, high-value work. That's already what they had in mind when they hired you, so it's hardly a big loss for them or their plans.

Quitting only works if you'll be better off by doing so. If you have a better job lined up, then quitting will improve your situation. If you have no job lined up, but can't bear to do the sales calls any more or provide this work for free, then quitting may be good by virtue of freeing you from those tasks. Don't quit over what you feel is owed to you, quit over a better situation which is available to you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. Did your boss ask you to solve those problems, and/or did your boss make any statements to the effect that you are the greatest thing that happened to his/her team?
2. Are the problems you are solving among the most critical issues his team is facing, and do they have the greatest (or any) ROI in terms of efficiency, value add, and bottom line?
3. Demanding a promotion rarely gets you one. I think you are trying to say that you will politely approach the topic and cautiously test the waters, to see if there are opportunities for promotion and what are the expectations and criteria for the higher level role. You will then share some examples of how your contributions thus far meet these criteria, and what would it take for you to receive a promotion given that you believe that you are qualified and deserving. Good luck!

Comment: 1. Yes they asked if I would do it on my down time. And yes they are exceedingly happy with it.
2. Yes they directly effect our ROI in all areas.
3. If I can manage to not go insane making sales calls. Yeah that probably what I should do. But I have confidence in myself or in people in general.. so ill probably just quit.

Comment: Above is a type should read " But I have **no** confidence in myself or in people in genera"

Answer (score 1):

**There's a critical problem in your thinking: Solving your boss' problems is what literally everyone is hired to do.**

Seriously - every non-manager's role is basically to be a solution of the boss' problems.  The work I do each day is because my boss is manager over an area and has problems within that area (new features need to get added, problems occurring in existing functionality, whatever.)  My job is to solve those problems - adding features, fixing bugs, whatever - but by solving those problems *I'm not doing my boss' job.*  My boss' job is to oversee the productivity of the people that have been hired underneath them.

So these pieces of software you've developed - assisting with workflow, finding data issues, etc - that *is not your boss' job*.  Your boss' job is to prioritize and delegate work to you and evaluate your performance - it's *management*.

So, once you understand that, you've got three options:

- Continue to look for areas you can streamline processes and develop
  new cost/time saving measures and get your boss' approval to
  implement them.
- Begin talking with the IT department within the company.  Show them
  what you can do.  Ask if they've got any openings or even small
  projects that you could take on (note: this will depend on being able
  to work for two different bosses or your getting approval to dedicate
  work time away from your current role.)
- Begin looking for entry level IT jobs that can use your skills.

... but talking with your *manager* with the assumption that you've been doing *their* job is not going to take you in any sort of productive direction.

Answer (score 1):

You did some excellent problem-solving work for your boss and your team. ALWAYS remember that, for it's the most important fact in this case.

It's always good to take it in this order:

1. "I've shown I can do good work and I'd very much like to do more."
2. "I hope to move into that line of work so I can be better paid and recognized."

Bosses hate it when people demand raises, because they hate saying no. And say no they must: getting raise money is a bureaucratic nightmare in most companies. So stick up for yourself and try to be compassionate to the boss at the same time.

Is it possible the boss never even said "thanks"?  Is it possible they're taking credit upon themselves?  If so, this boss of yours is not motivated by innovation. They don't encourage excellence and creativity from people on the team. Lots of bosses are like that.

You could say something like this to your boss, "I like working on these business-process problems. Is there any way I can do more of it?"  If the boss says something like "you're wasting my time, get back on the phone," well, some bosses are like that.

It's a good thing to know about your boss. Let's make that your "soon to be former boss". Don't waste any more time working for a company where it's OK if the bosses don't care.

If you can find somewhere they DO care about excellence, that's the place to work. Go work there. Don't look back.

When you write your resume and do your interviews, make it clear you want to do problem-solving work. Ask for a chance to do it with them.